# Only main() function executing in C

Tags: c, function

Starting to learn C. The `main` function is executing fine, but the program finishes running without ever executing the second function. I feel like I'm making a mistake here in the for loop in main.

```
int check_key_length(int count);

int main(void)
{
    char key[20];
    int count = 0; 

    printf("Enter key: ");
    scanf("%s", key);
 
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++) 
    {  
        if (key[i] != ' ')
            count++;  
    }  

    printf("Total number of characters in a string: %d", count); 

}


int check_key_length(int count)
{
    int set_amount = 26;

    if (count < set_amount)
        printf("Error: Your key is too short! Please input 26 chars\n");
    else if (count > set_amount)
        printf("Error: Your key is too long! Please input 26 chars\n");
    else
        string message = get_string("Enter string to encrypt: ");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Functions need to be called by someone. `main` is the only exception as it is automatically called by the startup code of your program. For any other function you must call it to be executed.

Comment: haven't I already called it? I called it by putting it up top, before main. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: The line on top is called a "function prototype" that only tells the compiler that somewhere else a function with that signature exists and just in case you might call it, it knows what to do.

Comment: Please learn the difference of *declaring* a function, *defining* a function and *calling* a function in C!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forward declared your function, provided a definition for it, but you need to call the function in your main for your machine to execute it, something like this calls your function as expected

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_key_length(int count);

int main(void)
{
    char key[27];
    int count = 0;
    int strLength;

    do {
        printf("Enter key: ");
        scanf("%s", key);

        strLength = strlen(key);
    } while(check_key_length(strLength) != 0);
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i < strLength; i++) 
    {
        if (key[i] != ' ')
        {
            count++;  
        }
    }

    printf("Total number of characters in a string: %d\n", count);

    return 0;
}

int check_key_length(int count)
{
    int set_amount = 26;

    if (count < set_amount)
    {
        printf("Error: Your key is too short! Please input 26 chars\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else if (count > set_amount)
    {
        printf("Error: Your key is too long! Please input 26 chars\n");
        return -2;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Note I had to modify the code a bit for it to build without any warning or error, I probably changed the behavior in a way you're not expecting so check my code before pasting it in

Comment: No problem! Even though I appreciate it, comments containing only "Thanks" messages are usually deleted for posterity, on stack overflow the preferred way to show an answer is correct/helped you is to mark it as the solution by clicking the tick icon on the top left of it